# Pendulum reference request

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I found on the net the following excerpt
[image]
Could someone help me giving the title, author(s) of this book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *ODE Architect Companion*, by CODEE (Consortium for ODE Experiments) / John Hubbard and Beverly West. Published by Wiley.

This is a book that comes with the software package "ODE Architect". It's a pretty old software package, though (the most recent edition was released c. 1999, I believe). Here's a link to its page on the CODEE website: [link](http://www.codee.org/software/ode-architect).

Answer (score 1):

A Google Books search for "the pendulum and its friends" finds
[ODE Architect Companion](http://books.google.ca/books?id=5-FUAAAAYAAJ)